# How to write this query using LinQ lambda expression

Tags: linq, join, lambda, entity

```
SELECT PropertyCommnets.commnet_content, 
       PropertyCommnets.commnet_date, 
       users.user_name, 
       propertycommnets.commnet_id 
FROM   PropertyCommnets  
       INNER JOIN aspnet_users 
               ON propertycommnets.userid = aspnet_users.userid 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON aspnet_users.userid = users.userid
```

i wrote this but is't correct:

```
from a in context.PropertyCommnets 
join b in context.aspnet_Users 
on a.UserId equals b.UserId 
join c in context.Users 
on b.UserId equals c.UserId 
where a.property_id == PropertyId 
select(c.user_name ).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: _"i wrote this but is't correct"_ Sorry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying with your `select` at the end. That's not valid syntax and `FirstOrDefault` is also incorrect compared to your sql query.

Try this:

```
from a in context.PropertyCommnets 
join b in context.aspnet_Users 
on a.UserId equals b.UserId 
join c in context.Users 
on b.UserId equals c.UserId 
where a.property_id == PropertyId 
select new {  
    commnet_content = a.commnet_content,
    commnet_date = a.commnet_date,
    user_name = c.user_name,
    commnet_id = a.commnet_id,
};
```

However, this is still query syntax not method/lambda syntax. Does it matter? With joins query syntax is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

a) Is there a specific reason why you join on aspnet_users?
You are not using aspnet_users.userid

b) Your attempt is Linq SQL not a Lambda expression.

c) Do you have a virtual collection of propertycommnets in your user model? if not I'd consider that. Then you could simply call upon user.propertycommnets and the the comments of that specific user.